# T SQL adding multiple new attributes to root node of XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a table `A` like:

```
 ID   X-value  Y-Value

 1      12       10
 2      11        4
 5       4        5
```

I have another table `B` that has:

```
ID   XML

1   somexml
2   somexml
3   somexml
4   somexml
5   somexml
```

How do I insert both the X and Y values as new attributes 'x-value' and 'y-value' into the Table B's XML root node?

Trying to come up with an update statement to update Table B xml to have the new attributes and their values added from table A.

Comment: Are you using MySQL, MS SQL Server or Sybase?

Comment: I am using MS Sql server

Comment: Add a few more rows with sample data would be great. Can you also specify the expected result?

Comment: I am trying to update all table B's XML. To have the two  new attributes (x-value , y-value) from table A based on ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid string based approaches...

But - regrettfully - `.modify` does allow for just one change at a time.
**EDIT: See the UPDATE section below!**

You might try this:

Your *mockup* tables

```
DECLARE @tblA TABLE(ID INT,X INT,Y INT);
INSERT INTO @tblA VALUES
 (1,12,10)
,(2,11, 4)
,(5, 4, 5);

DECLARE @tblB TABLE(ID INT,SomeXml XML);
INSERT INTO @tblB VALUES
 (1,'<root><SomeInnerNode test="1"/></root>')
,(2,'<root><SomeInnerNode test="2"/></root>')
,(3,'<root><SomeInnerNode test="3"/></root>')
,(4,'<root><SomeInnerNode test="4"/></root>')
,(5,'<root><SomeInnerNode test="5"/></root>');
```

--The `.modify()` will insert an attribute with the value of a result set's column:

```
UPDATE t SET SomeXml.modify('insert attribute x {sql:column("X")} into (/root)[1]')
FROM (
    SELECT a.X,a.Y
          ,b.SomeXml
    FROm @tblA a
    INNER JOIN @tblB b ON a.ID=b.ID
) t;
```

--Check the result

```
SELECT * FROM @tblB;
```

Just repeat this approach for each value separately.

### Another approach using `XQuery`

You can do the whole thing in one go by *re-creating* the XML using `XQuery`

```
UPDATE t SET SomeXml=SomeXml.query('
                                        <root> {attribute x {sql:column("X")}}
                                               {attribute y {sql:column("Y")}}
                                        {
                                            /root/*
                                        }
                                        </root>
                                  ')
FROM (
    SELECT a.X,a.Y
          ,b.SomeXml
    FROm @tblA a
    INNER JOIN @tblB b ON a.ID=b.ID
) t;

SELECT * FROM @tblB;
```

### UPDATE Great hint by the OP (Thx!)

I'd never tried this, but `.modify()` can add a buch of attributes in one go with a statement like this:

```
UPDATE t SET SomeXml.modify('insert (
                                     attribute x {sql:column("X")}
                                    ,attribute y {sql:column("Y")}
                                    ) 
                             into (/root)[1]')
FROM (
    SELECT a.X,a.Y
          ,b.SomeXml
    FROm @tblA a
    INNER JOIN @tblB b ON a.ID=b.ID
) t;
```

Comment: Thank you. I used a cursor with the first method. :)

Comment: I was able to add multiple attributes as follows
UPDATE TableA

SET TableAXmlColumn.modify('insert 

(

attribute xvalue {sql:variable("@xvalue")},

attribute yvalue {sql:variable("@yvalue")}

)

where TableAid = @id

Comment: @vamsireddy Hi, I added your hint to my answer. Thx again!